# Scala libraries that actually work with Cassandra

Tags: scala, cassandra, database, nosql

I know that this may be a duplicate question, but scala expands and develops too quickly. I asked this question a year ago and I must ask this question now: what is the best way to organize interaction between scala and cassandra? I heard about cassie, scalandra, etc, but I don't have enough experience to choose one.

I tried use Hector, but it for java, and I want use native lib for scala.

Comment: its wrong that hector is only for `java`,i am using hector for `scala` for `cassandra-cli`

Comment: @Govind Singh Nagarkoti i know that i can call java code in scala, but i hope that exist any native decision for scala. or you try tell me that hector now have scala implementation?

Comment: How does it matter if it's implemented in scala or in java? The datastax driver is in java but it's very good and you can use it from your scala code. It's not because it's in scala that it is faster/better.

Comment: @vptheron sorry for my noob question but why exist scala implementation of datastax driver("phantom" if i true)?